# Catching Different Number Types in Strings by Regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, numeric

I am trying to catch different number types (float, decimal, binary, octal and hex) **at the beginning of strings** with this regex:

```
/([0-9]*\.[0-9]*|0)|([1-9][0-9]*)|(0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+)|(0[0-7]+)|(0b[01]+)|(0)/
```

I write it according to PHP integer page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

But it is catching "a1", or only "0" part of "0xABC", I need to make it with single line of regex. What am I missing?

Comment: Your `([0-9]*\.[0-9]*|0)` is going to match first. Put that at the end.

Comment: When you say "at the beginning of the string" then you probably need to start the regex with a `^` . Because `^` is for the start of the string. Unless it's in a character class like f.e. `[^0-9]` then it's a negation of the characters between the brackets.  And those OR's `|` will try to match the first from left to right.

Comment: Maybe `/^(([-]?[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+|0[^0-9xXb])|([-]?[1-9][0-9]*)|(0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+)|(0[0-7]+)|(0b[01]+))/` ?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/yP7zQ3/1

Comment: It would be good if volunteers would not provide resolving advice in comments -- answering via comments too often leads to question abandonment.   https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296481/352329

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to offer some important tips to resolve and refine your pattern for this task.

- use `^` to anchor your match to the front if the input string
- group all of the alternation branches so that every branch is bound to the "start of string" anchor.
- several of the alternations begin with zero, so it makes sense to group these related subpatterns.
- It is essential that you use `\d*(?:\.\d+)` to ensure that a dot must be followed by a digit to qualify.

Suggested Pattern: (as multi-line pattern with `x` flag for readability)

```
  /^
    (?:\d*(?:\.\d)+
    |0(?:[xX][\da-fA-F]+|[0-7]+|b[01]+)?
    |[1-9]\d*)
  /x
```